# Multiple files upload - Blueimp jQuery uploader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, blueimp

I use a jquery plugin name "blueimp jquery file upload" - https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.

I was wondering how can i add dropdown values to the database for each file when uploading multiple files.

I have used the original javascript template for uploading files and i modified it a little. It looks like this.

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <form id="#fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;">/div>
           </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="title">
            <select name="title[]" >
                <option value="val1">val1</option>
                <option value="val2">val2</option>
            </select>
            </label>
            <label class="description">
                <span>Description:</span><br>
                <input name="description[]" class="form-control">
            </label>
    {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start upload-file" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
    {% } %}
    {% if (!i) { %}
        <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
            <span>Cancel</span>
        </button>
    {% } %}
        </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    {% } %}
</script>
```

I am trying to make it to work. I spend a lot of time today but don't want to gave up. If someone had expericne with this, please help me, give me direction.

i have found this but i cant figure it out how to make it work
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data

Thanks

Best Regards,
Darko

Answer (score 0):

See server/php/UploadHandler.php in function handle_file_upload try connect to db and save files details in database

Comment: There is already title atribute that i want tu use as you can see in the dropdown above :)